# HtmlHelper add query string to static files

Tags: cakephp, html-helper

I want to add a `version` parameter to my static files (for dealing with cache issues).

How can I do it? I think `HtmlHlper::css` or `HtmlHlper::script` don't get a query string...

Comment: If you're just trying to prevent caching, use `Configure::write('Asset.timestamp', true);` in your core.php file.

Answer (score 1):

why do you think that? did you try it?

```
$this->Html->script('/myfile.css?v=123&somequerystring=foo&even=more');
```

should work